# "python myscript" ignores "#!/usr/bin/env pythonX" where pythonX doesn't exist

Tags: python, macos, shebang

**Why doesn't `test.py` throw error `env: python3: No such file or directory` when Python 3 is not installed?**

My system (Mac OS X) has Python 2.7 installed, but not Python 3:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python -V
Python 2.7.12
$ /usr/bin/env python3 -V
env: python3: No such file or directory
```

File **test.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
print sys.executable
```

Executing **test.py:**

```
$ python test.py
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
```

I thought that since Python 3 does not exist on my system, having the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` will throw an error and terminate the script. But `env` actually selected the Python 2.7 interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shebang is interpreted by OS when it tries to execute the script.  Whey you type `python test.py`, the OS executes `python` and `python` executes the script (and `python` is found based on the current `PATH`) as opposed to being processed by the OS.

If you make the script executable (`chmod +x test.py`) and then try to execute it directly (e.g. `./test.py`), the OS will be responsible for running the script so it will look at the shebang to figure out what program is responsible to run the script.  In this case, it is `/usr/bin/env` which will look for `python3` and try to use that.  Since `python3` isn't there (or not findable on your `PATH`) you'll see the error.

Comment: I believe it's actually the `exec` family of functions that process the shebang line; I don't think the shell is involved.

Comment: The shebang is actually interpreted by the system call that attempts to execute the script. The first character of the shebang is `#` so that the shell ignores it.

Comment: It's a little hand-wavey about `/usr/bin/env`'s role (as the thing that actually does the `execvp`, with a search through the path, as opposed to a standard `execv` that requires an explicit fully-qualified path), but nothing here looks inaccurate outright.

Comment: [to be more complete/pedantic: the OS executes `/usr/bin/env`, and `/usr/bin/env` uses a C library call that does a PATH lookup and then does an `execv` to tell the OS to replace its process image in memory with Python]

Comment: @CharlesDuffy -- Yeah.  I think that it's probably OK to wave hands a little in this case.  I was more trying to get at when the shebang gets executed and when it doesn't.  The details of `/usr/bin/env` is a bit further down the rabbit hole than we need to go to get that idea across (and sometimes when you dig too deep, things get muddy)...

Comment: Current text seems like a good compromise -- explains what the `env` is there for and its role in the execution chain without getting into the mud.

Answer (score 2):

The shebang is only processed when you do `test.py`, running the file directly instead of running `python` with `test.py` as an argument. When you do `python test.py`, Python completely ignores the shebang line.